# I am unable to catch a ValueError exception, tried everything I know and still failing

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I am trying to cast a user input into an integer value in a try-block. If a ValueError is raised then print an error message and retry the while loop to get a new input. If a valid input is received then a break kicks the user our of the while loop and the value is returned.

However, every time I run the code in any variation, a ValueError is raised and the program stops. Literally, the exact exception I am catching is being raised and causing the program to crash.

```py
   def size_chooser(self):
    while True:
        cprint("Enter page size", color='red')
        user_input_value = input("---> ")
        if user_input_value == 'quit':
            val = None
            break
        else:
            try:
                val = int(user_input_value)
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("this exception block is working, try again")
    return val
```

The exact error message I get is:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError 
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'w'
```

What am I doing wrong, please help. Could it be a Visual Studio problem? I am using Visual Studio and everything works great in it except a niggling issue of importing outside the current folder failing. Only way around is to manually append to sys.path, which is not ideal but that's the only way I was able to import from across my sibling folders.

Comment: Your code works for me. Unable to reproduce the problem as described

Comment: I could be simplified though. You don't need `break` inside a loop inside a function. Directly return what you want to return. You also don't need the `else` clause since if input is `quit` you `break` (or if you accept the first suggestion, you `return`)

Comment: I am super confused too. I isolated the try by removing everything else and just wrote a function that tried to cast a string to an int and catch the exception, and even that fails. If nothing else makes sense is it likely an IDE problem you think?

Also thank you for the input on optimization.

Comment: Don't know. Try another environment. The problem doesn't seem to be coming from the code itself. (although in my try I changed `cprint` to `print`)